# Python hangs on Tkinter file dialogue

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a function which will allow me to browse to a file then return the path & name of that file. However my code keeps hanging after I've selected the file (the file name is returned and I don't get an error but the file dialogue window does not close and becomes unresponsive). I'm running OSX 10.9.1 Python 2.7.6 (in the release notes it mentioned solving a similar sounding bug to this...). I also have numpy 1.8.0. and matplotlib 1.3.1 (but neither of those have been imported so shouldn't affect anything, right...?). Thanks!

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

def myfile():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    root.destroy() #tried with and without this line but it had not effect
    return file_path

if __name__=='__main__':

 print   myfile()
```